# How to know which variable is returned by Promise.all in case a dynamic array of Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

```
const promisesArray = [];

if (condition) {
  const promiseA = fetchA();
  promisesArray.push(promiseA)

}
if (condition) {
  const promiseB = fetchB();
  promisesArray.push(promiseB)

}
if (condition) {
  const promiseC = fetchC();
  promisesArray.push(promiseC)
}

// Could have 1, 2 or 3 elements
const [???] = await Promise.all(promisesArray);
```

With this pattern, how could I dynamically bind promise results to variables ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to destructure results of a dynamic number of async calls with Promise.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55992223/how-to-destructure-results-of-a-dynamic-number-of-async-calls-with-promise-all)

Comment: Not the easiest way because in practice my function had parameters, but passing null instead of a promise when my condition was falsy did the job! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option #1:**

I think I'd tag each result in an object and then when you iterate through the results, you can know which are there and which are not.  You can't really use named destructuring directly from the `Promise.all()` results because you don't know which results are in the `Promise.all()` array and which are not.  So, it seems you need to iterate the results and dynamically adapt to which results are there.  My guess is that there's a better overall way to code this particular case, but you'd have to show us your real code for us to offer a better approach based on that.  Anyway, here's a generic iteration solution:

```
const promisesArray = [];

if (condition) {
  const promiseA = fetchA().then(result => ({a: result}));
  promisesArray.push(promiseA)

}
if (condition) {
  const promiseB = fetchB().then(result => ({b: result}));
  promisesArray.push(promiseB)

}
if (condition) {
  const promiseC = fetchC().then(result => ({c: result}));
  promisesArray.push(promiseC)
}

// Could have 1, 2 or 3 elements
let results = await Promise.all(promisesArray);
let combined = Object.assign({}, ...results);
// now you have a single object that has each results, tagged with a key that
// represents which function it came from
```

**Option #2:**

You could also push a placeholder for each result, even if there's no asynchronous operation for it and then you would maintain position in the array and could directly destructure.

```
const promisesArray = [];

if (condition) {
  const promiseA = fetchA();
  promisesArray.push(promiseA)
} else {
  promisesArray.push(null);
}

if (condition) {
  const promiseB = fetchB();
  promisesArray.push(promiseB)
} else {
  promisesArray.push(null);
}

if (condition) {
  const promiseC = fetchC();
  promisesArray.push(promiseC)
} else {
  promisesArray.push(null);
}

// Could have 1, 2 or 3 elements
let [aResult, bResult, cResult] = await Promise.all(promisesArray);
// results that were skipped will be null
```